# XAML Style to add border around element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This should be quite simple, but no matter what I search, I find nothing helpful.

I want to make a XAML style so that all `FrameworkElement`s (could be `Panel`s instead, or if I must, `StackPanel`s) with a certain style -- lets call it `Bordered` -- have a border around it. I know I could just put the border around it myself, but I feel like there must be a way to do it based on style.

I figured it might be something like this, but the property `Children` below is read only.

```xml
<Style x:Key="bordered" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                <Border BorderThickness="5">
                    <!-- Here I don't know how to do it for a generic panel -->
                    <!-- Also, I cant bind Children -->
                    <StackPanel Children="{TemplateBinding Children}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So basically I want to know how can I wrap a border around the contents of an element?

Comment: I see at least two problems with your attempt above: `StackPanel` doesn't even have a `Template` property, so you can't replace the template like that (it's simply not a templated control), and even if it did, the `Children` property is not a valid binding source. Other than that, maybe you could've gotten around the `{TemplateBinding}` issue by using an `ItemsControl` with a `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel`, but that seems really kludgy. Your question is very broad, so not really answerable, but maybe you should be looking into adorners. That's a more common way to add flourishes to elements.

Answer (score 1):

Abraham,

The best solution I could find is to wrap the StackPanel in a ContentControl:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="StackBorderTemplate" TargetType="Control">
            <Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="20"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>


        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource  StackBorderTemplate}">
            <StackPanel/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

This is the best solution, or the closest thing to a solution that I could find.

You can customise the style of the border to your needs from the ControlTemplate.

Thanks,